# Angular and jasmine: components variable is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, bdd, karma-runner

I'm trying to test my app. One of the components I'm using (angularytics) relies on a variable `_gaq`. This is set in the index.html file by inserting googles tracking code:

```
var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-39511600-3'],['_trackPageview']];
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
```

I'm testing a state transition:

```
it('should transition to profile state', function(){
    state.transitionTo('root.salons_profile');
    scope.$apply();
    expect(state.current.name).toBe('root.salons_profile');
});
```

At some point the component is being called but it's `_gaq` variable hasn't been initiated.

I tried to create a spy to mock the variable and even just initialised the variable in the `beforeEach()` function however neither have worked.

How can I create this `_gaq` variable so that the `angularytics` component can use it when it gets called?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just declare a global variable called `_gaq` within your spec?

Comment: @MichaelBenford I've tried that too. I wonder if it's being unset somewhere